# Visual studio SDK - Get current line seperator

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-sdk

I'm working on a visual studio extension that requires me inserting lines of text into the current user document. Since line separators are not a universal thing, and every operating system, text editor or end user uses a different style, I would like to make sure I am using the correct style for the current environment when I am inserting text.

I tried looking for some VS SDK global that stores this value but I couldn't find it.  All I found was `VSConstants.VSStd97CmdID.LineBreak` which is supposed to be the command number for inserting a line break. Unfortunately I need this as a string and not a command.

So, does there exist such a global somewhere ? The editor itself defiantly stores this since there is a menu option for it

Comment: Are you looking for [LineBreakLength](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.text.formatting.itextviewline.linebreaklength?view=visualstudiosdk-2017#Microsoft_VisualStudio_Text_Formatting_ITextViewLine_LineBreakLength)?

Comment: As can be seen [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/encodings-and-line-breaks), VS supports 5 different types of line breaks. 4 of them have the same length. Knowing the length could have been useful if only CRLF and LF were supported, but that is not the case.